# Scroll elements in a 100vh height page up and out of view

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML document with a `height` of `100vh`. The element contains a title. Now when I scroll nothing happens as expected. What I need is an effect that the page stays the same and my title is scrolling up and out of the viewport. How can I achieve that?

My code simplified:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: *The page stays the same* - are you just wanting a fixed background image?  It is very unclear what you are trying to achieve - if you just want the title to scroll out of view, then increase the size of it's container so it is bigger than the viewport

Comment: The reason you will not have any scrolling is because the `#wrapper` element takes up as much space as the `body` element. To make your title scroll, you can either add another element after `#wrapper` or increase the size of `#wrapper` and apply your background styles to the body element.

Comment: What im trying to achieve is that the title is scrolling out of the wrapper when i scroll. There is no fixed background image involved. What i need is, is there a solution, maybe with jquery or whatever that when i scroll not the page is scrolling but the element itself

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the opposite way - not fixing the to-be-scrolled element, but the contents element which you put into the background by using a negative z-index:

Apply `position:fixed` to the wrapper and move it to the background with `z-index: -1`. Erase `position: absolute` from the `h1` to reset its position to `static` to allow it to scroll.

For the scrolling to be possible, you either need enough height for the title element (at least 150% or more), or another (possibly invisible) element that follows afterwards, like in my example below.

The text centering inside `h1` can be done via flex (see below).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.something_else {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"> wrapper contents here... </div>
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="something_else"></div>
```